# How do I count the number of sentences in C using ".", "?", "!"?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm fairly new to coding. I'm having trouble with my "CountSentences" function. I compare the string to "." , "?" , and ! to count a sentence.  It only adds one to the sentence counter no matter how many of the punctuation marks I have in the string. Am I using strcmp wrong to get my desired result and is there another way I can approach this?

```
#include<cs50.h>

#include<ctype.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<math.h>

//function for letter count
int count_letters(string s)
{
    int numberofLetters = 0; // counter

    //loop as long as string length
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n;  i++)
    {
        //if character is alphanumeric
        if(isalnum(s[i]) != 0)
        {
            numberofLetters++; //increase counter
        };
    };
    return numberofLetters; //return new counter number
};

//function for word count
int count_Words(string w)
{
    int numberofWords = 0;//counter for words declared
    int i = 0; // counter for character in string

    if(w == NULL) // if nothing
    {
        return numberofWords; // return Wordcount of 0
    };


    bool spaces = true; //truth value for space

    //if character is not null terminating character
    while(w[i] != '\0')
    {


        if(isblank(w[i]) != 0) //if character is blank
        {
            spaces = true; //its a space
        }
        else if(spaces) //if no more space and a letter is present add to words
        {
            numberofWords++; //add to number of words counter
            spaces = false;
        };
        i++;// increase chracter count in string w

    };

    return numberofWords; //return total word counter
};

//function to count sentences
int count_Sentences(string l)
{
    //variable counter for marks
    int countMarks = 0;

    //loop iteration using the number of characters in string
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(l); i < n; i++)
    {
        //check if character is ?, . , or !
        if(strcmp(&l[i], "!") == 0  || strcmp(&l[i], ".") == 0  ||  strcmp(l, "?") == 0)
        {
            countMarks++;// sentence counted
        };

    };
    // return the total number of marks
    return countMarks;
};


int main (void)
{
    string text = get_string ("Text: ");

//to check the functions bug checker
    printf("Number of letters: %i\n", count_letters(text));
    printf("Number of words: %i\n", count_Words(text));
    printf("Number of sentences: %i\n", count_Sentences(text));

    //Coleman Liau Index
    int grade = round(0.0588 * (100 * (count_letters(text)) / (count_Words(text))) - 0.296 * (100 *(count_Sentences(text)) / (count_Words(text))) - 15.8 );



    if(grade <= 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if(grade < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    };
};
```

Comment: Your code is comparing all the *rest* of the input with a one-char string. I suggest `if(l[i] == '!')` etc. Aside: it's ill-advised to use `l` (the letter ELL) as variable name. It is too easily confused with `1` (the digit ONE) making the code hard to read, and open to mistakes.

Comment: You might like to know about the function family `ispunct()` and `isspace()` and `isalpha()` and so on, declared in `ctype.h`.

Comment: regarding: `   };
};`  do not place a semicolon `;` after a closing brace `}`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>` for the `printf()` and similar functions

Comment: OT: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`

Comment: rfegarding; `int grade = round(0.0588 * (100 * (count_letters(text)) / (count_Words(text))) - 0.296 * (100 *(count_Sentences(text)) / (count_Words(text))) - 15.8 );`  the function: `round()` returns a `double`, not a `int`  Here is the syntax:   `double round(double x);`

Comment: regarding: `if(strcmp(&l[i], "!") == 0  || strcmp(&l[i], ".") == 0  ||  strcmp(l, "?") == 0)`  This will NOT work because a single char from `l[]` is not a string.  Suggest:  `if( l[i] == '!' || l[i] == '.' || i[i] == '?' )`   Notice the use of single quotes rather than double quotes so comparing a character rather than a string.  Notice the use of appropriate horizontal spacing for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if(strcmp(&l[i], "!") == 0  || strcmp(&l[i], ".") == 0  ||  strcmp(l, "?") == 0)
```

`strcmp` compares two *strings*. In C, our "string" is essentially "the char-sized data starting at the place this pointer points to, and continuing until a null terminator". The cs50 library *does not change this and does not give you a real string type*; it only provides a typedef and some helper functions for reading input. (It also, sadly, does not and realistically cannot give you a real *text character* type, which `char` also is **not**; but that is beyond the scope of this answer.)

`&l[i]` is a *pointer* into the middle of the `l` string, starting at offset `i`. When that pointer is used by `strcmp`, it will treat the "string" as *everything from that character to the end of the original string* - because that's where the null terminator is. It will, in particular, **not** treat the single `l[i]` char as a separate string, in general, because the next char is in general not a null terminator. So,

> It only adds one to the sentence counter no matter how many of the punctuation marks I have in the string.

In fact, it only even adds one because your string ends with one of those marks.

To compare individual chars, don't use `strcmp`. It is not intended nor fit for the purpose. A `char` is a single entity, so it can be compared just fine with `==`. You just need to have something appropriate on both sides of the comparison.

Recall, in C single quotes are used for char literals, and indexing into the char array (equivalently, "indexing" into a char pointer, which performs the equivalent pointer arithmetic) gives you a char. Thus:

```
if (l[i] == '!' || l[i] == '.' || l[i] == '?')
```

Comment: Aside: "C single quotes are used for char literals" --> In C, `'!'` is a _character constant_.   C has 2 _literals_ defined: _string_ and _compound_, but not _char literal_.  Both of which can have their address taken, unlike a _constant_.  In C, `'!'` is type `int`.

Comment: `strchr` is MUCH bore suitable

Answer (score 2):

You indeed need to see if the *one* character `l[i]` is any of `.`, `?` or `!`. To do that, you can test if that is equal to any of these character constants, i.e.  `l[i] == '!' || l[i] == '.' || l[i] == '?'`

Or you can use the function [`strchr`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.2) that will look for a given character in a given string and return a pointer to that character, or a null pointer if the character is not found. A null pointer will be considered as falsy in `if`, and  and a non-null pointer truthy. So we can look for `l[i]` in the string `".?!"`:

```
if (strchr(".?!", l[i])) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works well when `l[i] != 0`, which it cannot be due to prior `n = strlen(l); i < n;` as `strchr(".?!", 0)` is not-`NULL` too.